# In the following list how can I access the core number?

Tags: python, list

```
l = ['-t2=Idle -D2=/sv/socket0/local-core-01/local-cpu-00 -T2=0 \\\n',
     '-t3=Idle -D3=/sv/socket0/local-core-02/local-cpu-01 -T3=0 \\\n',]
```

I want to add the core number into a variable preferably.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a regex in a list comprehension:

```
l = ['-t2=Idle -D2=/sv/socket0/local-core-01/local-cpu-00 -T2=0 \\n',
     '-t3=Idle -D3=/sv/socket0/local-core-02/local-cpu-01 -T3=0 \\n',]

import re

out = [m.group(1) if (m:=re.search(r'core-(\d+)', s)) else None for s in l]
```

Output:

```
['01', '02']
```

For integers:

```
out = [int(m.group(1)) if (m:=re.search(r'core-(\d+)', s)) else None for s in l]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: could you give more detail on the m.group(1) and what exactly it does, while trying to run I get an error that m is not defined

Comment: The above code requires python ≥3.8 (assignment expression). `m.group(1)` returns the first captured group in the regex, i.e. the digits.

Comment: I have updated and I am still getting the same error